# Attribute type single_selection with array_store needed

Tags: php, crud, shopware

I'm wondering why Shopware 5 is ignoring the array_store column for the attribute type single_selection. It seems that we need a complete mapped entity to these kind of attributes. But in this case I need a simple key/value pair. So, how to create a single_selection attribute on any attribute table with array_store's?

In relation to the docs here, but not further explained for single_selection: https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/attribute-system/#define-own-single-and-multi-selection

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `combobox` type for a simple key-value pair. There's also a code example with some explanation in the docs you've mentioned: [Backend View Configuration](https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/attribute-system/#backend-view-configuration)